# VueJS (Element UI) -> absolute positioned div in relative div on v-for

Tags: css, vue.js, element-ui

I try to render a list of `<el-card>` items to which I apply a `transition-group`.
I have a back and front `<el-card>` that flips when clicking a button.

To have the flip transition looks good, I need the cards to have this style : `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0` but the problem is that all the cards are stacked.

If I remove this style, all the cards are displayed side by side but the flip effect has unwanted behavior: the `back` item is visible under the `front` item.

You can find an exemple [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/j2wn75l1v).

I'm looking for some help to resolve this.

Thank you.

Michael

Comment: I don't understand what does it means to `look good`. If you set all the cards to `0,0`, they will be at `0,0`. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Actually, the transition looks good to me (just a card flipping).
My problem is that I want my cards not stacked. You may not have seen but there are 3 stacked card in the example and I want them side by side

Comment: You're positioning them absolutely, so of course they will be stacked. The wrapping parent has no `position: relative` so they will all be positioned absolutely relative to the `<body>` element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because all the front and back elements of the card are positioned absolutely **with respect to the `<body>`** element. None of the parents have `position: relative`, so of course they will all appear at coordinates (0,0) of the page.

What you want is to actually use `position: relative` on the parent element, ideally on a per-card level. Give the parent a class, for convenience of selection:

```
<div class="card" v-for="card in cards" v-bind:key="card">
```

And then you assign the parent a fixed width and height (which is `180px`, since you've defined the same for the front/back faces of the card anyway), and assign `position: relative` to it:

```
.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
}
```

Proof-of-concept fix: https://codesandbox.io/s/xjq08j5n1p

---

Side note: you will still realize that your example remains broken, in the sense that flipping a card will flip **all** the cards. That is because you are storing the flip state on the parent app instance, not on the individual card levels. I suggest that you create a child component for each card, so that you can store their flipped states individually.

Answer (score 0):

[Terry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49852183/80766) was well spot on. I just want to add the complete example for working functionality.

Since you already had a `.flipper` class declared, I used that to add the `position:relative` block:

```
.flipper {
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
}
```

Remember that for `position:relative` to work, a size must be set. Otherwise, since the `.flipper` has no in-flow element inside, its size will be 0.

Also, set the appropiate width of the children

```
.front,
.back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

We need `100%` since we are already setting the width on the parent.

I converted `flipCards` to an array of booleans, and modified the `flipCardSwitch` function.

```
flipCardSwitch: function(index) {
  // needed because of https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats
  this.$set(this.flipCard, index, !this.flipCard[index]);
}
```

Of course, you need to update the `on-click`.

`@click="flipCardSwitch(i)"`

**Working code:** https://codesandbox.io/s/71512v9qvx